# starting dhcpd failed (Centos)

Tags: centos, dhcp

i have a issue related to dhcp 
i have configured my dhcp according to my ip and all ...

but it fails. when i try to start the service...

i tried to trouble shoot and i stopped the firewall (iptables)
i disabled selinux.

is there any other area i need to consider..
is there anything that stops dhcpd service to start from.

Comment: "failed to start" is too little information.  Look at your error logs.  But better still post this over at serverfault.com

Comment: Don't you want to provide us a little more information? Or if you solved the problem, just tell us what was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `/var/log/messages` when starting dhcp (with `tail -f /var/log/messages`) you'll see why it's failing. most likely it's going to be something obvious, but if you can't work it out, post the error message in your question, so everyone can see what's happening. you may also want to give the network configuration (`/sbin/ip add`), usual dhcp problems are related to wrong subnet definition etc.

also, try running `dhcpd -t` to test your config files.